# Tag Cloud For google webmaster tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am using webmaster tools for my web site. I heard sometimes ago that I can generate tag cloud using google webmaster tools. But don't know how.
Is there any way to create a script for multiple tags, that I can use that in my website for seo?

Comment: A tag cloud is a UI element, has nothing to do with SEO. Can you clarify what you want some more?

Comment: I want to add multiple keywords to my website using some tool. 

is it possible through google webmaster tools?

Comment: "Add" them in what way, to where? To the page? To the search results?

Comment: I do not want to use pages as my code base supporting multiple websites. means there are multiple websites there running on a single code.
what does it mean "add to the search results"?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly it is you want to do? In its current form this makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer and that is https://tagmanager.google.com/?hl=en

I can create tags in google tag manager.